# Autoregressive model with panel data in r

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

I have the following dataset dt

```
Y     date       segment
 10   2019-11-11    1
 12   2019-11-12    1
 9    2019-11-13    1
 ...
 ..
 14   2019-12-15    5
 12   2019-12-16    5
 10   2019-12-17    5
```

I want to build an autoregressive model such that

```
 Y(segment, dat)_{t} = beta1*Y(segment,dat)_{t-1} + beta2*Y(segment,dat)_{t-2}...
```

while I have to problems with just one segment as I would do something like this:

```
library(dynlm)
Y <- dt$Y
AR2 <- dynlm(ts(Y) ~ L(ts(Y)) + L(ts(Y), 2) )
```

I am not sure how to do with multiple segments at the same time

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use `lm()` like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- tibble(
  Y = sample(1:50, 200, replace=TRUE),
  date = rep(seq(as.Date("2019-11-11"), by="1 day", length=40),5),
  segment = rep(1:5, rep(40, 5))
)

dt <- dt %>%
  arrange(segment, date) %>%
  group_by(segment) %>%
  mutate(
    Y1 = dplyr::lag(Y,1),
    Y2 = dplyr::lag(Y,2)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

fit <- lm(Y ~ Y1 + Y2, data=dt)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: summary(fit) gives me R^2 = 1 using on your example (and also on my data) , looking at the data I see Y1 = Y2 = Y , so maybe there s a bug in this code?

Comment: That would occur if you used stats::lag rather than dplyr::lag. Possibly you're using an old version of dplyr. Or perhaps it is calling stats::lag for some other reason. In any case, I've made the calls explicit now.